# Can't boot windows 7 from boot menu after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I've just finished installing Ubuntu, and while it crashed at first and I had to download the Ubuntu boot repair software and run it live from a USB drive to fix the problems I had, I'm still unable to boot Windows.

Before installing Ubuntu, I had Windows 7 profx64 installed on my PC. And my plan was to dual boot Windows & Ubuntu.

My problem is that when I power on my PC, I get the boot menu to choose which OS I'd like to work with, and while both OSes are there, when I choose Windows, I get the following error message:-

"error: can't find command 'parttoll'."
"error: invalid EFI file path"

How can I solve these two?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows 7 is past EOL and should be replaced. This is a good opportunity to wipe clean and start fresh.

Comment: Well. That's definitely true, but I honestly don't wanna give MS my money and windows 10 is not so cheap where I live. Can I boot windows from a USB like I did with Ubuntu after I torrent it or something?

Comment: It's EOL. It doesn't get security updates and immediately became a flashing red target for bad actors the day it went EOL. It should be replaced, with the only exception being if you **never** give it network access.  Ubuntu is free (in cost and as in freedom)